# how to set checkbox status on index page and toggle content in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i'm trying to build a toggle between dark & light mode; but i'm having trouble getting my iframes to follow the switch...

Here's my current jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var switched = $('#mode');
  
  switched.on("change", function(){
    if (switched.is(':checked')){
      $('html').removeClass('dark');
      $('html').addClass('light');
      localStorage.setItem('mode','light');
    }
    else{
      $('html').removeClass('light');
      $('html').addClass('dark');
      localStorage.setItem('mode','dark');
    }
  });
  var mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
  if (mode == 'dark') {
    switched.prop( "checked", false );
    $('html').removeClass("light");
    $('html').addClass("dark");
  }
  if (mode == 'light') {
    switched.prop( "checked", true );
    $('html').removeClass("dark");
    $('html').addClass("light");
  }

});
```

My code fetches the state of a checkbox with the #mode id, and gives/removes the corresponding class to :root. The switch then works with CSS like this:

```
:root,
:root.dark {
  --color-bg: #263238;
  --color-fg: #ffffff;
}
:root.light {
  --color-bg: #ffffff;
  --color-fg: #000000;
}
```

But on [my index page](https://amy-testfo.forumactif.com), i have a chatbox embedded in an html , so I also wrote this bit of code, which i can apply to the chatbox page that's in the iframe:

```
$.get('https://amy-testfo.forumactif.com/', function(datas){ 
    var coche = $('#mode',datas);
    var mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');

    if(coche.not(':checked')){
      $('html').removeClass("light");
      $('html').addClass("dark");
    }
    if(coche.is(':checked')){
      $('html').removeClass("dark");
      $('html').addClass("light");
    }

    if (mode == 'dark') {
      $('html').removeClass("light");
      $('html').addClass("dark");
    }
    if (mode == 'light') {
      $('html').removeClass("dark");
      $('html').addClass("light");
    }

  });
```

But when I check the checkbox, the chatbox stays in dark mode and needs a page reload in order to actually switch, so that's my problem. I tried using `.on('change')` in the second script but it didn't do much :(

Thank you in advance if you decide to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control both the IFRAME and the main page, you can create a function within the IFRAME page and call it from the parent.

For example, in your IFRAME have a function called: toggleTheme. In my example, since you have two themes, its easier to just remove both of those classes and add a class compared to if statements.

```
function toggleTheme(theme){
   $("html").removeClass("dark light").addClass(theme);
}
```

Then give your iframe an ID if it doesn't already.

ie `<iframe ..... id="chatBox"></div>`

Then in the parent you can call that function like this:

```
const chatBox = document.querySelector("#chatBox");
chatBox.contentWindow.toggleTheme(theme);
```

**document.querySelector("#chatBox")** Will reference the iframe itself.

**contentWindow** will get the window object of the iframe.

**toggleTheme** is the function that you created from above

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this, I managed to get it working :)